Magento 2 - Custom product select attribute is not shown in layered navigation

I have created custom product attribute input type select with configuration below in code sample that is provided.
After creating attribute I assigned added options to that attribute in magento admin on attribute configuration page.
I checked default attribute set and attribute is there under default even though I didnt specifically assigned  attribute to default attribute set.
Attribute is shown on product page in magento admin and I set values on few products.
When I filter by '*' in search field, search result page is shown with all products (also the ones where I assigned the values to that attribute) but attribute filter is not shown in layered navigation, only category filter.

Am I missing something?
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Product::ENTITY,
        'p_type',
        [
            'group' => 'General',
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Product Type',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'backend' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'facet_sort_order' => BucketInterface::SORT_ORDER_MANUAL,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'filterable' => 1,
            'filterable_in_search' => 1,
            'searchable' => 1,
            'visible' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'is_used_in_spellcheck' => true
        ]
    );

Attribute is shown in product configuration and I assigned different values to few different products. When I go to search page, attribute is not shown in layered navigation even though there is no any other filter applied and all products are shown.
